# Summing a list of variables by a list of variables in SAS

Tags: list, sas

What would be the most efficient method to sum a group of variables by a different group of variables? I am working with a large number of files which are different in structure so for some I have to define the variables to sum and sum by are going to be different. I have taken care of the list problem but need help getting the sum out using these macro variables that I am using to store the list of variables.

I come from a Stata background, where I'd just collapse (sum) `sumvars', by (`byvars').

Comment: Same concept, use the 'group' variables in a BY statement within PROC MEANS. https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/proc_means_basic

Comment: Note, as posed, your question does not meet the SO guidelines, please see the how to ask a question post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks. I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1):

Summing items in SAS is not obvious. (Or was not for me when I began.) An easy way to accomplish this is to use **proc means**, **proc freq** or **proc sql**.

In your case the syntax goes like this. VarX are your grouping variables. We always have to sort the data in SAS.

```
proc sort data=Begin; by var1 var2 var3 ; run; 

proc means data=Begin noprint; /*Use noprint unless you want huge printouts to screen.*/
    by Var1 var2 var3;
    output out=Output_file_name
    sum(Variable_you_wish_to_sum1)=Name_of_summed_variable1
    sum(variblae_you_sum2)= 
    ....
    ;
run;
```

Proc means has a huge catalog of options see http://www.okstate.edu/sas/v8/saspdf/proc/c24.pdf for more.

Edit: Newer documentaion: 
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1qnc9bddfvhzqn105kqitnf29cp.htm

Comment: Thanks very much. I was trying to do it the data step way but that ended up being very complicated.

Comment: It's probably better to use a documentation reference that's not two decades old, here's the latest: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1qnc9bddfvhzqn105kqitnf29cp.htm

Comment: @Reeza Good point. Updated answer to contain the suggested link.